# What is the correct IP address conversion from number?

Tags: powershell, ip, ip-address

I am trying to convert number into IP address using powershell method and checking same online, I am getting 2 different result.

**Example:**

```
number = 16812043
result1 = 11.136.0.1 #using powershell
result2 = 1.0.136.11 #https://codebeautify.org/decimal-to-ip-converter
```

I have tried below code

```
function Convert-NumberToIP
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number
    )

    [Int64] $numberInt = 0
    
    if([Int64]::TryParse($number, [ref]$numberInt))
    {
        if(($numberInt -ge 0) -and ($numberInt -le 0xFFFFFFFFl))
        {
            ([IPAddress] $numberInt).ToString()
        }
    }
}

Convert-NumberToIP -number 16812043
```

I am getting 2 different result not sure which 1 is correct, or should I update the function.

Comment: There is a binary conversion.  16812043 = 0x1 (1), 00 (00), 88 (136), 0B (11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IPAddress]::Parse() can parse out IP addresses from multiple data types (including integer or string)

```
[Int] $ipInt = 16812043
([IPAddress]::Parse($ipInt) | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString)
```

Also, if you want to do the inverse (converting an IP address to a integer), can do this using the following...

```
[String] $ipStr = '1.0.136.11'
[IPAddress]::HostToNetworkOrder([BitConverter]::ToInt32([IPAddress]::Parse($ipStr).GetAddressBytes(), 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder()` method to flip the endianness of the octets represented by your decimal number:

```
PS ~> [ipaddress]::new([ipaddress]::NetworkToHostOrder(16812043)).IPAddressToString
1.0.136.11
```

Comment: I have updated `[ipaddress]::new([ipaddress]::NetworkToHostOrder(16812043)).IPAddressToString` instead of `([IPAddress] $numberInt).ToString()` in above function and tried `Convert-NumberToIP -number 16778241` but getting `*Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of 
valid values.
Parameter name: newAddress"*`

Comment: @NaveenKumar I don't know what you updated your function to, but `[ipaddress]::new([ipaddress]::NetworkToHostOrder(16778241))` works just fine

Comment: when I am converting 281470698521601 using `[ipaddress]::new([ipaddress]::NetworkToHostOrder(16778241))` I am getting an error it's unable to do it any idea?

Comment: @NaveenKumar I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe. What is the exact error message?